# Multiple issues with HTML, It wont center, and the footer is placing things all over

Tags: css, html

I am programming a HTML Email to be sent out and can not figure out why its going crazy like this.

I have sent out emails in the past using the same pieces of code ( the footer sections) and it worked fine then and wont work this time around. The code seems to render just fine in chrome via the Dreamworks "real-time Preview"  but does not render correctly when opened in Internet Explorer or Edge, or more importantly the outlook mail system. I am new to HTML still and have racked my brain over this to no avail. I spent hours adding in "align="center"" and trying many other things to fix not only the insane footer placement but also the fact it wont center!

[Image of what i want it to look like when done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOx2f.png)
Thanks for the help!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>8,22,17 eNewsleter 477 and mikrotik</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 700" align="center">

<table id="Header" width="700" height="75" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/home.asp" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_01.png" height="78">
   </a>
  </td>
  
  <td valign="top" align="right" height="36">
    <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_03.png" width="130">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/linktechnologiesinc/" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_04.png" height="48"></a>
   
   <a href="https://twitter.com/linktechsdotnet" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_05.png" height="48"></a>
   
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/9211300/" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_06.png" height="48"></a>
   
  </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr align="right">
  <td colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">
   <a href="tel:314-7350270" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_07.png" width="120"></a><a href="mailto:sales@linktechs.net" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_08.png" width="170"></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<!--LINKS TO HEADER FILES IN ORDER
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_01.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_03.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_04.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_05.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_06.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_07.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_08.png
-->
<!-- Save for Web Slices (8,22,17 eNewsleter 477 and mikrotik.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="700" height="923" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td> 
   <a href="https://www.towercoverage.com/En-US/Dashboard/neworder"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,22,17_477_MikroTik_Sale/8,22,17-eNewsleter-477-and-mikrotik_01.png" width="700" height="420" alt="Caution: 477 Section 5.3 data your billing system provides is wrong! Don’t understate your actual coverage area by 90+% using data provided by your billing system. You must have accurate RF propagation maps to get this data correct!"></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="http://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/showspecials.asp"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,22,17_477_MikroTik_Sale/8,22,17-eNewsleter-477-and-mikrotik_02.png" width="700" height="305" alt="Mikrotik Sale at Link Technologies Inc." style="display: block;"></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewContent.asp?idpage=77"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,22,17_477_MikroTik_Sale/8,22,17-eNewsleter-477-and-mikrotik_03.png" width="700" height="198" alt="Link Technology Offers Support" style="display: block;"></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->

<!-- BEGIN OF FOOOTER -->
 

 <table id="Footer" align="center" style="width:700px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 
<!--insert additional parts below this line-->
 
<!-- Start of PowerLink Ad -->
  <tr style="position: relative;display: block; padding:0;margin: 0;">
   <td colspan="4">
    <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2251&idcategory=0" target="_blank">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,8,2017_Surveillance/5th-Power-Link-Footer.png" alt="PowerLink is a battery powered PoE injector with built-in Wi-Fi access point. No more running test cable! 8 watt or 15 watt options available." width="700" height="168" usemap="#Map2" border="0" style="display: block">
    </a>
    <map name="Map2" style="z-index: 50">
       <area shape="rect" coords="344,113,446,155" href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2233&idcategory=0" target="_blank" alt="8 Watt">
       <area shape="rect" coords="495,114,594,155" href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2251&idcategory=0" target="_blank" alt="15 watt">
    </map>
   </td>
  </tr>
<!-- End of PowerLink Ad -->

<!--insert additional parts above this line-->
  <tr style=";display: block;">
   <td>
    <a href="https://www.towercoverage.com//" target="_blank">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_01.png" width="175" height="88" alt="TowerCoverage.com">
    </a>
   </td>
   
   <td>
    <a href="http://www.ispradio.com/" target="_blank">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_02.png" width="175" height="88" alt="ISP Radio Network" style="display: block">
    </a>
   </td>
   
   <td>
    <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewContent.asp?idpage=33" target="_blank">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_03.png" width="175" height="88" alt="Hotspot Network Manager" style="display: block" align="center">
    </a>
   </td>
   
   <td>
    <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2046&idcategory=0" target="_blank">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_04.png" width="175" height="88" alt="Power Router v4" style="display: block" align="center">
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
       
        <tr style="position: relative;display: block; padding:0;margin: 0;">
   <td>
    <a href="##HTMLNewsletterURL##" target="_blank">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_05.png" width="233" height="25" alt="View as HTML">
    </a>
   </td>
   
   <td style="padding: 0">
    <a href="http://news.linktechs.net/members.aspx?Task=FF&amp;S=1&amp;N=54&amp;Format=HTML&amp;E=support%40linktechs.net">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_006.png" width="234" height="25" alt="Forward to a Freind">
    </a>
   </td>
   
   <td>
    <a href="##OptOutURL##">
     <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_07.png" width="233" height="25" alt="Opt Out">
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
 
<!--LINKS FOR THE IMAGES IN ORDER!
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_01.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_02.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_03.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_04.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_05.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_06.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_07.png
-->
<!-- END OF FOOTER -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.  Please reduce your question to a [mcve] (and please do not SHOUT)

Comment: Try adding some CSS on the body tag in order to center your tables - `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: It seems to me that i already have " leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"" placed in the body tag of my HTML. And the issue is still present. thanks for the question advice

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question for anyone who happens across this. I do not understand why, but adding a second table to the bottom most part of the page fixed the issue.

here is the code fixed this way.

Even though i answered myself, and this is a solution to the problem. I do not understand as to why this is the solution. I just threw things at it until i figured something out that worked. If you know why feel free to answer again and get credit for the true answer.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>8,22,17 eNewsleter 477 and mikrotik</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

  <table id="Header" width="700" height="75" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/home.asp" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_01.png" height="78">
        </a>
      </td>

      <td valign="top" align="right" height="36">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_03.png" width="130">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/linktechnologiesinc/" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_04.png" height="48"></a>

        <a href="https://twitter.com/linktechsdotnet" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_05.png" height="48"></a>

        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/9211300/" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_06.png" height="48"></a>

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="right">
      <td colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">
        <a href="tel:314-7350270" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_07.png" width="120"></a>
        <a href="mailto:sales@linktechs.net" target="_blank"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_08.png" width="170"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!--LINKS TO HEADER FILES IN ORDER
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_01.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_03.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_04.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_05.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_06.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_07.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeader_08.png
-->
  <!-- Save for Web Slices (8,22,17 eNewsleter 477 and mikrotik.psd) -->
  <table id="Table_01" height="923" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="699">
        <a href="https://www.towercoverage.com/En-US/Dashboard/neworder"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,22,17_477_MikroTik_Sale/8,22,17-eNewsleter-477-and-mikrotik_01.png" width="700" height="420" alt="Caution: 477 Section 5.3 data your billing system provides is wrong! Don’t understate your actual coverage area by 90+% using data provided by your billing system. You must have accurate RF propagation maps to get this data correct!"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/showspecials.asp"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,22,17_477_MikroTik_Sale/8,22,17-eNewsleter-477-and-mikrotik_02.png" width="700" height="305" alt="Mikrotik Sale at Link Technologies Inc." style="display: block;"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewContent.asp?idpage=77"><img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,22,17_477_MikroTik_Sale/8,22,17-eNewsleter-477-and-mikrotik_03.png" width="700" height="198" alt="Link Technology Offers Support" style="display: block;"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->

  <!-- BEGIN OF FOOOTER -->
  <table id="Footer" align="center" style="width:700px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <!--Add extras below this line-->

    <!-- Start of PowerLink Ad -->
    <tr style="position: relative;display: block; padding:0;margin: 0;">
      <td colspan="4">
        <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2251&idcategory=0" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,8,2017_Surveillance/5th-Power-Link-Footer.png" alt="PowerLink is a battery powered PoE injector with built-in Wi-Fi access point. No more running test cable! 8 watt or 15 watt options available."
            width="700" height="168" usemap="#Map2" border="0" style="display: block">
        </a>
        <map name="Map2" style="z-index: 50">
       <area shape="rect" coords="344,113,446,155" href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2251&idcategory=0" target="_blank" alt="8 Watt">
       <area shape="rect" coords="495,114,594,155" href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2251&idcategory=0" target="_blank" alt="15 watt">
    </map>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- End of PowerLink Ad -->


    <!--Add extras above this line-->
    <tr style="position: relative;display: block; padding:0;margin: 0;">
      <td>
        <a href="https://www.towercoverage.com//" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,8,2017_Surveillance/Footer-1-TowerCoverage.png" width="175" height="88" alt="TowerCoverage.com" style="display: block">
        </a>
      </td>

      <td>
        <a href="http://www.ispradio.com/" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,8,2017_Surveillance/Footer-2-ISP-Radio.png" width="175" height="88" alt="ISP Radio Network" style="display: block">
        </a>
      </td>

      <td>
        <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewContent.asp?idpage=33" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,8,2017_Surveillance/Footer-3-HSNM.png" width="175" height="88" alt="Hotspot Network Manager" style="display: block" align="center">
        </a>
      </td>

      <td>
        <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=2046&idcategory=0" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/2017/002_August/8,8,2017_Surveillance/Footer-4-PR4.png" width="175" height="88" alt="Power Router v4" style="display: block" align="center">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="Footer2" align="center" style="width:700px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="##HTMLNewsletterURL##" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_05.png" width="233" height="25" alt="View as HTML">
        </a>
      </td>

      <td style="padding: 0">
        <a href="http://news.linktechs.net/members.aspx?Task=FF&amp;S=1&amp;N=54&amp;Format=HTML&amp;E=support%40linktechs.net">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_006.png" width="234" height="25" alt="Forward to a Freind">
        </a>
      </td>

      <td>
        <a href="##OptOutURL##">
          <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_07.png" width="233" height="25" alt="Opt Out">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <!--LINKS FOR THE IMAGES IN ORDER!
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_01.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_02.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_03.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_04.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_05.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_06.png
/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewFooterSliced_07.png
-->
  <!-- END OF FOOTER -->
</body>

</html>
```